# Put the Xpath element's text to array

Tags: ruby, arrays, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium. The problem is the following:

The doc structure:

```
<div class="jsSkills oSkills">
 <a class="oTag oTagSmall oSkill" href="/contractors/skill/software-testing/" data-contractor="749244">software-testing</a>
 <a class="oTag oTagSmall oSkill" href="/contractors/skill/software-qa-testing/" data-contractor="749244">software-qa-testing</a>
 <a class="oTag oTagSmall oSkill" href="/contractors/skill/blog-writing/" data-contractor="749244">blog-writing</a>
</div>
```

I need to obtain all `a`'s text to be in array like:

```
{"software-testing", "software-qa-testing", "blog-writing"}
```

I tried this:

```
contrSkill = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[contains(@class, 'jsSkills')]").text
puts contrSkill
```

but got this:

```
"software-testingsoftware-qa-testingblog-writing"
```

Please explain how to appropriately make an array.

Comment: What you claim is an array is not an array. It is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get all of the link elements you want (using `find_elements`). Then you can iterate over each link and collect its text into an array (Ruby has a `collect` method that helps with this).

```
# Get all of the link elements within the div
skill_links = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//div[contains(@class, 'jsSkills')]/a")

# Create an array of the text of each link
skill_text_array = skill_links.collect(&:text)
p skill_text_array
#=> ["software-testing", "software-qa-testing", "blog-writing"]
```